# What about Sql Server Data Tools for VS2012 being incompatible with Sql Server 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

In what seems to be a very odd turn, I am trying to create a Sql Database project in Visual Studio 2012, and am getting this nutty error:

[image]

And clicking on either link leads to a Page Not Found at Microsoft.com, which is odd in itself.

From the bare text of the error message, which is (for search purposes):

> **Unable to open Database Project**
>
> This version of SQL Server Data Tools is not compatible with the
>   database runtime components installed on this computer.

Considering that I have Sql Server 2012 Developer Edition installed on the workstation, this seems incredible.  I can open or create a database project in VS2008 with Sql Server 2012 DE installed, so why not VS 2012?

Comment: and astonishingly it is working in Vs2013 but not in vs2012

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I Installed SQL Server 2012 Service pack 1 yesterday and then I started getting the problem you describe in Visual Studio 2012. Not only with database projects; I could not use the SQL Server Object Explorer, not open sql-scripts and lots of other weird database related errors. Always with the same message:

"This version of SQL Server Data Tools is not compatible with ... bla, bla, bla ..."

This solution helped me: https://web.archive.org/web/20150315060703/http://blog.wharton.com.au/2012/11/16/sql-server-2012-sp-1-breaks-sql-server-database-projects/
Hope this can help you too

**Update:** 
With the *March 2013 Release* it seems you have to also update the SQL Server Data Tools available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015) See the comments in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/03/06/sql-server-data-tier-application-framework-march-2013-available.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Just downloading and installing the SQL Server Data Tools cured this for me; http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=274984

Comment: @PGallagher, worked for me too. Might wanna make this a full blown answer so I can vote for you ;)

Comment: I downloaded & installed the tools (Oct 2013) from the link (here) in the **Update:** from @JorgenH and this solved the described problem for me.

Comment: October 2013 update is out at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015 - just installing the update worked for me.  I didn't have to uninstall anything.

Answer (score 37):

Just downloading and installing the SQL Server Data Tools cured this for me;

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=274984

Comment: Updated link for people finding this on Google. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320745

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me in visual studio 2012 on an existing project after I installed visual studio 2013. Installing the 2012 tools fixed it as others have said but the link provided in previous answers wasn't the one I needed. the link that did it for me is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case the downloaded SQL Server Data Tools is not working. You can try to download this version:

[SQL Server Data Tools download](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320745)

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue but in my case its due to version difference.Refer attached image. so once upgrade with right version then prob solved to me. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvI1J.jpg)