# I don't know why im getting a System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an application that was working while I was running from localhost using localdb. My computer froze and I had to force restart my computer. Now, I am getting this error on a function that previously worked.

Could my database have gotten corrupt when I force restarted my computer? If this is not the case, what else could be the issue?

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: @dbugger `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-GroceryAssistant-20140222144706;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-GroceryAssistant-20140222144706.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` Also, the login/logout/register functionality still works, this is what VS creates with the MVC project.

Comment: is the aspnet-GroceryAssistant-201402221‌​44706.mdf file still there?

Comment: Yes, its there. I can see the file.

Comment: Can you find the database in the Server Object Explorer in VS and open it?

Comment: Yes, i can open it. If I try to right click on the table and select Show Table Data or New Query, i get an error `An incompatible DacFx Version is installed`

Comment: Think you may have a system update that has gone awry. check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798422/what-about-sql-server-data-tools-for-vs2012-being-incompatible-with-sql-server-2)