# Visual Studio 2012 database project "incompatible"

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

We've a problem with a database project on Visual Studio 2012 (11.0.61219.00 Update 5), it says "incompatible".

We have SQL Server 2014 installed on our computer.

We've tried to install
[SSDT 11.1.50730.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015), but it hasn't changed anything.

We've tried to install [DacFX](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36842) , but it hasn't resolved the problem either.

We've tried to repair Visual Studio and SQL Server, but nothing changed...

We don't know what to do anymore... So maybe the community can help on this one ?

Thanks in advance !

Edit (with screenshot) :

[Microsoft SQL Server Data Tool can't be loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgvmD.png)

[Database project incompatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBdE6.png)

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So, we've also tried to :
Copy the entire contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120 into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin as suggested [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/865077/cannot-open-existing-or-create-new-sql-server-database-project). We've successfully loaded our database project, but Visual Studio crashes when we try to generate a deployment script, so this is not over yet.

Any idea how to fix this one ?

Comment: Relevant link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15798422/what-about-sql-server-data-tools-for-vs2012-being-incompatible-with-sql-server-2

Comment: What's the exact error message?